# Menu bar icons disappearing when connecting USB device

Tags: macos, usb, menu-bar

If I plug something into one of the USB ports on my Mac 17″ (after upgrading to Yosemite) my Menu Bar at the top of the desktop keeps disappearing and reappearing.
The icons keep flashing on and off.  This only happens when I plug something into a USB port.

It's very annoying and frustrating as my Mac now fails to fully recognise my iPhone and I am unable to sync it to my iTunes and my graphics tablet is acting weird too.

Yosemite has not been a success with me yet, it just seems to be one thing going wrong after another! Is anyone else having this issue?

[image: Menu Bar]

Comment: Please be more specific about the model # of the iMac. You can use this handy chart to figure it out: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201634 . Does this happen with any USB port and any type of USB device? What kinds of USB device are you using? You don't indicate if this happens when the Keyboard & mouse are plugged in. If it doesn't happen with these devices, does the menu bar disappear when you plug a device into the USB port on the keyboard?

Comment: The menu bar icons are presented by the "SystemUIServer" process. Due to the fact that those icons are disappearing, the `SystemUIServer` process is likely crashing. You might be able to find a crash log at `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` that has the name `SystemUIServer` in it somewhere. Those crash logs will likely provide helpful information on why the process is crashing. I'd be suspicious of the disk/wiper icon (some "cleaning" utility?) that isn't disappearing with the rest (it's normal for Spotlight to stay in the menubar when `SystemUIServer` is not running).